# Where did St. Bernard say that incontinence in ecclesiastics is one of the greatest persecutions the Church could suffer?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, sexuality, alphonsus-liguori

St. Alphonsus Liguori writes in [*Dignity and Duties of the Priest or Selva* p. 112](https://archive.org/details/alphonsusworks12liguuoft/page/n117/mode/2up):

> St. Bernard said that incontinence in ecclesiastics was one of the greatest persecutions that the Church could suffer.
>
> [ original, [*Selva di materie predicabili* ch. 6 "Del peccato d'incontinenza"](http://www.intratext.com/IXT/ITASA0000/__P2Z8.HTM#-FDY):]
> *Dice s. Bernardo che l'incontinenza degli ecclesiastici è la maggior persecuzione che oggidì patisce la chiesa.*

Where may I find the actual quote of St. Bernard to which St. Alphonsus alludes?

Comment: I do own quite a lot of the translated work of St Bernard de Clairvaux, and I do recognise the style, but I don’t recognise the quote. 

I would recommend searching for the quote in French an/or in Latin. English was not his first language ;)

Comment: @ABMK Probably Latin,; I'm not sure St. Alphonsus either read or spoke French, but he was well versed in Latin. The linked translated version of *Dignity and Duties of the Priest* contains almost 2000 footnotes, most of which are still in the Latin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

St. Alphonsus bases his statement upon what St. Bernard wrote in [sermon 33 of his *86 Sermons on the Song of Solomon* p. 224](https://books.google.com/books?id=b1I7AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA224), where he commentates on [Isaias 38:17](https://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=27&ch=38&l=17-#x) ("Behold in peace is my bitterness most bitter"). St. Alphonsus writes this right after what you quoted:

> On the words of Ezechias [*sic*], "Behold in peace is my bitterness most bitter" ("*Ecce in pace amaritudo mea amarissima*") [[Is. 38:17](https://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=27&ch=38&l=17-#x)], says the holy Doctor [St. Bernard],
>
> [[Grimm's  transl. of St. Alphonsus](https://archive.org/details/alphonsusworks12liguuoft/page/n117/mode/2up)'s  transl. of the :]
>
> > the Church has suffered much from the sword of the tyrant and from the infection of heresy, but she suffers still more from the **incontinence of the unchaste ecclesiastic**, who by his scandals drags the bowels out of his own mother.

[St. Bernard's original  in the  original of St. Alphonsus](http://www.intratext.com/IXT/ITASA0000/__P2Z8.HTM#-FDZ):

> *Amara prius in nece martyrum, amarior in conflictu haereticorum, amarissima in **luxuria ecclesiasticorum*** ["lust of clerics"]*. Pax est, et non est pax: pax a paganis, pax ab haereticis, et non pax a filiis; filii propriam matrem eviscerant.*
>
> [The  in the  [transl. of St. Alphonsus](https://archive.org/details/alphonsusworks12liguuoft/page/n117/mode/2up) is a bit different:]
> *Amara prius in nece Martyrum, amarior in conflictu hæreticorum, amarissima in **moribus domesticorum*** ["domestic morals"]*. Pax est, et non est pax: pax a paganis, pax ab hæreticis, sed non profecto a filiis.*

[St. Alphonsus's  transl.](http://www.intratext.com/IXT/ITASA0000/__P2Z8.HTM#-FDZ) is somewhat free-flowing:

> La chiesa, dice, patì già grande amarezza dai tiranni che uccisero tanti martiri; maggiore amarezza patì poi dagli eretici che infettarono tanti suoi sudditi; ma la più grande amarezza e persecuzione è quella che ora patisce dagli stessi suoi figli, che sono gli **ecclesiastici disonesti**, i quali co' loro scandali cavan le viscere ad essa lor propria madre.
>
> [[DeepL transl.](https://www.deepl.com/translator.html#it/en/La%20chiesa%2C%20dice%2C%20pat%C3%AC%20gi%C3%A0%20grande%20amarezza%20dai%20tiranni%20che%20uccisero%20tanti%20martiri%3B%20maggiore%20amarezza%20pat%C3%AC%20poi%20dagli%20eretici%20che%20infettarono%20tanti%20suoi%20sudditi%3B%20ma%20la%20pi%C3%B9%20grande%20amarezza%20e%20persecuzione%20%C3%A8%20quella%20che%20ora%20patisce%20dagli%20stessi%20suoi%20figli%2C%20che%20sono%20gli%20ecclesiastici%20disonesti%2C%20i%20quali%20co%27%20loro%20scandali%20cavan%20le%20viscere%20ad%20essa%20lor%20propria%20madre.):]
> The church, he says, already suffered great bitterness from the tyrants who killed so many martyrs; greater bitterness did she then suffer from the heretics who infected so many of her subjects; but the greatest bitterness and persecution is that which she now suffers from her own children, who are the **dishonest ecclesiastics**, who with their scandals gouge out the bowels of their own mother.

[Eales's  transl. of St. Bernard](https://books.google.com/books?id=b1I7AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA224):

> It was bitter at first in the death of the martyrs; more bitter afterwards in the conflict with heretics; but most bitter of all now in **the [evil] lives of her members**. […] Peace it is, and yet it is not peace. There is peace from heathens, and from heretics; but not from her own sons.

Thus it seems there are a two different MSS of St. Bernard with slight variations between them. The MS St. Alphonsus used is less "sanitized".

Comment: Many thanks for posting this answer.

Comment: @jean-marie Thanks for asking! It's a very good quote.